# Make image appear behind a black background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I want to let an image partially appear behind a black background.
Now I have a `UIView` with a black background and an `UIImageView` with the image.
Can I somehow alpha just for some parts of the black `UIView`, so that the image behind appears?
Is there a method which sets alpha Value for some pixels of a view?

Code:

```
darkView = [[ShowView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
darkView.alpha = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview: darkView];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testPic.png"]];
imageView.alpha = 1.0;
[darkView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: If you add the imageView to the darkView, the imageView will be on top and totally visible regardless of the alpha of the darkview. You might be better off adding a grid of subviews to the imageView and changing their alphas.

Comment: You can apply a mask to some part of your view and change the alpha to this mask

Comment: Might be you can use a translucent black image instead of black color.

Comment: @tiguero: how can i add such a mask to change alpha value?

Comment: @Patrick: i dont know if i get you right, but that is not exactly what i want, because than i am restricted to the grid of subviews. I want the alpha values of the black view to dissapear lets say randomly.

Comment: you just need to apply it to the mask of the layer of your view: CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
mask.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]; [yourview layer].mask = mask;

Comment: after a second thought i think your problem is probably simpler, did you try just to change the order your are adding your subviews. Can you achieve what you want by adding your darkview last and change its transparency?

Comment: @tiguero: thank yout. Actually the order the views where placed was good. The idea with the mask in the end did it! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You now have it as you should, the image in front of the black background, but you have to put the image with alpha 0; (from the visual editor or)

```
imageView.alpha = 0.0;
```

To make the image appear you just have to run the following code from a button or something:

```
UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |   UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.alpha = 1.0; 
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```